# PhPMyAdmin Error #1064; Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm trying to put together a MySQL database for a forum, And when I try to make a section table I keep encountering a problem

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = INNODB' at line 7

Here's the code:

```
 CREATE TABLE sections (
sect_id          INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sect_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
sect_desc     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX sect_name_unique (sect_name),
PRIMARY KEY (sect_id)
) TYPE=INNODB;
```

Comment: its `ENGINE` and not `TYPE`

Comment: It used to be `TYPE` on MySQL 3 and, if I remember correctly, it was allowed on MySQL 4 too,. The `TYPE` keyword was replaced by `ENGINE`, deprecated, then removed altogether some years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sections (
  sect_id          INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sect_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
sect_desc     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX sect_name_unique (sect_name),
PRIMARY KEY (sect_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

To mention the type of engine use `ENGINE` keyword.